# Spring Security with AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver and i18n

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, spring-security

I am stuck, probably missed something in docs or made some small mistake.

Spring Security 3.0.5 was integrated in my Spring MVC 3.0.5 app. **AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver** is used for Locale detection and localisation works ok except for Security error messages.

I copied messages.properties from spring security package and renamed and added to existing **"messageSource" bean (ResourceBundleMessageSource)** with value list.

As said earlier all texts and messages are localised correctly, except Security seams to use hardcoded English messages.

Any ideas how to solve this?

**UPDATE:**
My xy-servlet.xml contains:

```
...
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
...
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>defaultMessages</value>
            <value>securityMessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and files

- `defaultMessages.properties`
- `defaultMessages_en.properties`
- `defaultMessages_de.properties`
- `defaultMessages_sl.properties`

and

- `securityMessages.properties`
- `securityMessages_en.properties`
- `securityMessages_de.properties`
- `securityMessages_sl.properties`

but `defaultMessages` work ok. `securityMessages` does not. I made small changes in all `securityMessages` files, but they are ignored and the hardcoded english messages are displayed.

**UPDATE v2:**
My dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.sampleapp1" />
<context:annotation-config />

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources/ directory -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>defaultMessages</value>
            <value>securityMessages</value>
            <value>org/springframework/security/messages_de</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean> 

<!-- Persistence -->
<bean id="myPMF" class="org.springframework.orm.jdo.LocalPersistenceManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceManagerFactoryName" value="transactions-optional"/>
</bean>     

<!-- Form Validator -->

</beans>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, solution!
**Bean for security messages apparently must me declared in applicationContext-security.xml**
and not in app context xml config... I did not find this anywhere in manual! 
In my case correct solution is bean in applicationContext-security.xml:

```
    <b:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <b:property name="basenames">
            <b:value>secMessages</b:value>
        </b:property>
    </b:bean>
```

Thanks to **@bluefoot** and **@jtoberon** for some ideas.

**UPDATE:**
To work this properly web.xml must contain **localizationFilter** before **springSecurityFilterChain**, my web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- i18n -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>localizationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<!-- i18n -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>localizationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping> 
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping> 


<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Check lines after i18n comments.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Spring MVC, and I didn't know that the file `xy-servlet.xml` wasn't the application context configuration file. Anyway I'm glad it worked.

Comment: I'm using Spring 3.2 and seem to face this same problem, but unfortunately this solution doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you did it (you didn't say), but to use the messages bundle that is shipped with spring security (instead of hard coded text messages), I just have to declare a [`ResourceBundleMessageSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html) bean and set the [`basenames`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html#setBasenames%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) property:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>org/springframework/security/messages_pt_BR</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

That will change the messages to pt_BR, by making spring using this bean instead of the default one (no need to copy the file to somewhere else, assuming, of course, you have the jar on your classpath).

Comment: @bluefoot Please check my updated question. I do not know how to use your answer. Should I use:`<value>org/springframework/security/securityMessages_sl</value>`?

Comment: why are you creating your own properties? some of them are already into spring security core's jar. Probably your files are not being found into the classpath. Just remove `<value>defaultMessages</value> <value>securityMessages</value>` and replace it by `<value>org/springframework/security/messages_de</value>` (assuming that `xy-servlet.xml` is your application context configuration file) and see what happens.

Comment: no difference, I'm keep getting the hardcoded english messages. FYI: defaultMessages are my app custom messages and multilanguage is working without problems

Comment: can you post your entire application context configuration file so we can take a look and see what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ideas:

1. Is there a chance that the security messages are not on the classpath? Are your resource files all in the same directory? Are you putting them in WEB-INF/classes, and if not then how do you know they're on the classpath?
2. Do you have a namespace or key conflict? In other words, are default values for the security error messages already defined in the other resource file (the one that's working)?

Comment: Thanks for ideas! **1.** How do I check if messages are on the classpath? All files are in the same directory and in WEB-INF/classes **2.** In my defaultMessages I do not believe I have namespace or key conflict.