# Spring i18n Vs Spring security

Tags: spring, internationalization, spring-security

I configured my project to be internation but now i am trying to change spring security custom messages without success... I already read and tried some things but without success. I can se usual messages, but not spring security messages.

here is my servlet-context.xml:

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Tiles -->
<beans:bean  id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver">      
    <beans:property 
        name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>                
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.projectMvc" />


<!-- default locale  -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" id="localeResolver"> 
    <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="es"/> 
 </beans:bean> 


 <interceptors> 
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
         <beans:property name="paramName" value="language"/> 
    </beans:bean> 
 </interceptors> 

<!-- Messages files -->
<beans:bean id="messageSource"  name="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="/resources/messages/messages" />
</beans:bean>
```

here is my spring-security.xml:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/test" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/home" access="permitAll" />

    <form-login  default-target-url="/home"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/test" />
</http>


<authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

       users-by-username-query="
          select username,password,enabled,fullname
          from users where username=?" 

       authorities-by-username-query="
          select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur 
          where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  " 

    />
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

**UPDATE 1**
I tried your solution, copying spring security files and change them without success..
After i read this thread [Spring Security with AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver and i18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572377/spring-security-with-acceptheaderlocaleresolver-and-i18n)   i tried that solution too without success
here is my updated servlet-context.xml file:

```
    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Tiles -->
<beans:bean  id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver">      
    <beans:property 
        name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>                
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.projectMvc" />

 <!-- default locale pt_PT -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" id="localeResolver"> 
    <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="pt_PT"/> 
 </beans:bean> 

<!-- Messages files -->
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basenames">
    <beans:list>
        <beans:value>/resources/messages/messages</beans:value>
        <beans:value>/resources/messages/securityMessages</beans:value>
    </beans:list>
 </beans:property>



</beans:bean>

<!-- com o parametro locale no URL conseguimos definir o locale que quisermos -->
 <interceptors> 
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
         <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang"/> 
    </beans:bean> 
 </interceptors>
```

Here is my updated web.xml

[part1](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/812/80760783.png)

[part2](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/515/17151547.png)

Answer (score 2):

Probably a little late answer, but someone else facing similar issue might find it useful:

Your problem is that security beans are in root web application context, but `messageSource` is in the servlet application context source. This means that security beans are unaware of your message source. **Simply move your message source definition to the root web application context.**

Comment: Can you explain how we can move the message source definition to the root web application context?

Comment: Are you using XML or Java config?

Comment: I'm using XML, at the moment I define a bean of class `org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` with basename `classpath:org/springframework/security/messages` (as per http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#localization) but it doesn't work with my login page.

Comment: If you can update your answer to be more precise it would be great, otherwise I might ask a new question about this.

Comment: Well this boils down to the topic of understanding what *root* context is and what *servlet* context is (answered many times here on SO). The important thing is in which XML file you are defining the *message source* bean. It needs to be defined in XML loaded by `ContextLoaderListener` in your `web.xml`.

Comment: My `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` bean is defined in a XML file which is defined in `contextConfigLocation` context-param. So I guess that the message source is in root web application context already. Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you tried this,

1. Copy message files from `org.springframework.security` and change
   them.
2. Configure your message source with these files.

By default Spring security uses `org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityMessageSource` This is from javadocs

> All Spring Security classes requiring messge localization will by
>   default use this class. However, all such classes will also implement
>   MessageSourceAware so that the application context can inject an
>   alternative message source. Therefore this class is only used when the
>   deployment environment has not specified an alternative message
>   source.